# CUDA: Is It Possible to Use All of 48KB of On-Die Memory As Shared Memory?

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, gpgpu, gpu-shared-memory

I am developing a CUDA application for GTX 580 with CUDA Toolkit 4.0 and Visual Studio 2010 Professional on Windows 7 64bit SP1. My program is more memory-intensive than typical CUDA programs, and I am trying to allocate as much shared memory as possible to each CUDA block. However, the program crashes every time I try to use more than 32K of shared memory for each block.

From reading official CUDA documentations, I learned that there is 48KB of on-die memory for each SM on a CUDA device with Compute Capability of 2.0 or greater, and the on-die memory is split between L1 cache and shared memory:

> The same on-chip memory is used for both L1 and shared memory, and how much of
> it is dedicated to L1 versus shared memory is configurable for each kernel call
> (Section F.4.1)
> http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/Fermi_Tuning_Guide.pdf

This led me to suspect that only 32KB of one-die memory was allocated as shared memory when my program was running. Hence my question: Is it possible to use all of 48KB of on-die memory as shared memory?

I tried everything I could think of. I specified the option `--ptxas-options="-v -dlcm=cg"` for nvcc, and I called `cudaDeviceSetCacheConfig()` and `cudaFuncSetCacheConfig()` in my program, but none of them resolved the issue. I even made sure that there was no register spilling and that I did not accidentally use local memory:

```
1>      24 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
1>  ptxas info    : Used 63 registers, 40000+0 bytes smem, 52 bytes cmem[0], 2540 bytes cmem[2], 8 bytes cmem[14], 72 bytes cmem[16]
```

Although I can live with 32KB of shared memory, which already gave me a huge performance boost, I would rather take full advantage of all of the fast on-die memory. Any help is much appreciated.

*Update:* I was launching 640 threads when the program crashed. 512 gave me a better performance than 256 did, so I tried to increase the number of threads further.

Comment: How many threads are you launching?

Comment: I was launching 640 threads when the program crashed. 512 gave me a better performance than 256 did, so I tried to increase the number of threads further.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is not related to the shared memory configuration but with the number of threads you are launching.

Using 63 register per threads and launching 640 threads give you a total of 40320 registers. The total amount of register of your device is 32K, so you are running out of resources.

Regarding to the on-chip memory is well explained in the Tom's answer, and as he commented, check the API calls for errors will help you for future errors.

Comment: pQB is correct, registers are your limit here. One correction: it's 32K 32-bit registers, not 32Kb.

Comment: I was running out of registers, indeed. Thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

Devices of compute capability 2.0 and higher have 64KB of on-chip memory per SM. This is configurable as 16KB L1 and 48KB smem or 48KB L1 and 16KB smem (also 32/32 on compute capability 3.x).

Your program is crashing for another reason. Are you checking all API calls for errors? Have you tried cuda-memcheck?

If you use too much shared memory then you will get an error when you launch the kernel saying that the were insufficient resources.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I was checking API calls for errors, and none was detected. I will try cuda-memcheck to see if there is anything suspicious.

Comment: Actually, I just found that I was missing an error. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Also, passing parameters from the host to the GPU uses the shared memory (up to 256 bytes) so you will never get the actual 48KB.

Comment: not in this case. the device in questions a compute 2.x device and kernel arguments are passed in constant memory not shared memory